# Adding POST Method within Jersey Class

Tags: java, jersey

Let's say I have a Jersey JAX-RS api end-point for handling `http://<some_path>/foo`. Ignore the `...`.

```
@Path("foo")
public class FooResource

 @GET
 @Produces("application/json")
 public response getMethod(...)
```

I want to create `POST` end-point for `foo/{id}/bar`, where `id` is a path parameter and there's a body associated with the `HTTP POST`.

Example: `HTTP POST foo/1/bar with body: { data : "...." }`.

How can I add this `POST` method within the `FooResource` class? I tried an inner class, but it didn't work when I tested with `Postman`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  @POST
  @Path("{id}/bar")
  @Produces("application/json")
  public response myPostMethod(...)
```

You can have path at method level. This will have your post method accessible via /foo/{id}/bar